# How to config TexStudio on Mac when I am using Miktex?

Tags: miktex, texstudio, mac

I am currently using Miktex and Texstudio on Mac, how should I configure it in "Commands" so it also downloads the missing packages on the fly? If you can share the configs or a screenshot of the config details, that would be really helpful!

Answer (score 0):

`TeXStudio` uses the packages loaded by `MikTeX`, so it's `MikTeX` you need to configure to add additional packages on-the-fly. To do that follow these steps:

1. open the `MikTeX Console`
2. go to the `Settings` option (bottom one in sidebar)
3. in the tab `General` you'll see three choices how missing packages should be handled
4. choose either one of the first two as the last one won't install any packages automatically

Success!

*Answer to the link question*

1. open `TeXStudio`
2. click on `Help`
3. select the option `Check LaTeX installation`
4. A new document opens containing all relevant information about your system, the MikTeX installation, path, TeXStudio etc.

Usually TeXStudio locates the MikTeX installation automatically as MikTeX adds its main directory to the path.

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick response! I am a very naïve follow-up here, how can I make sure my texstudio is linked to miktex properly? Currently, now if I check the "Build" and then "($PATH)", it shows "usr/local/texlive/2012/bin/x86_64-darwin" is that fine, or should I make any changes there (or anywhere else), thanks again so much in advance!

Comment: You can check that quite simple. I'll add those steps to my answer.

Comment: Those are super helpful, thank you again so so much!

Comment: My pleasure. I have a question though. In your first question you mention using a Mac, TeXStudio and MikTeX. Yet in your comment you say the path contains texlive2012. The way you present that path looks awfully like Linux. I don't know Mac OS (thought is was based on BSD), but can you check whether there are files in that decade old texlive installation? It might interfere with your MikTeX/TeXStudio combination.